# Automatic creation of several vectors in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

I would like to create several vectors automatically in R. Each vector contains several variables (integers), which are selected randomly according to ranges for each vector.

For instance, the following shall create 20 vectors with 3 integer variables between the given ranges.

Number of vectors: V=20

Amount variables: Var=3

1<= Var1 <=10

1<= Var2 <=30

1<= Var3 <=20

Comment: What did you try? What step are you struggling with? Since this is a learning exercise there is no sense in just giving you a finished recipe... So what have you tried? If you don't know at all where to start I'd suggest looking into `sample` (i.e. `?sample`) and `sapply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sample` in `sapply` and `replicate`.

```
replicate(20, sapply(list(1:10, 1:30, 1:20), sample, 1), FALSE)
```